# Application of newtonian mechanics to waves and microscopic objects

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, atoms

I was reading a book which mentioned that since electron has wave nature application of newtonian mechanics is no longer possible, however while solving numericals on waves i have often used newton laws of motion. So what really is the problem with their application in this case.

Comment: Explain electron diffraction through crystals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bit deeper than this. The electron behaves both as a wave *and* as a particle, and this property will already give you some headaches if you are going to try to apply Newtonian Mechanics to it. But there is more.

If you take Rutherford's model of the atoms, which is that common one with the electrons orbiting the nucleus, just like planets around the Sun, there is a problem. According to Classical Physics, the electron should actually lose energy while it is spinning around the nucleus and, eventually, falling into the nucleus, with the subsequent collapse of all matter. However, obviously matter is stable. Otherwise, we wouldn't be here discussing this question.

Böhr solved this problem quantizing the energy in the electron's orbitals (similar to what Planck has done before with his energy quanta). That is, the energies that the electrons can assume around the nucleus are very specific, which is something we don't observe in the classical world.

Concisely, weird stuff appears when we are talking about electrons. Things which do not exist in Newtonian Mechanics and, therefore, you can't treat the problems with the same formalism (unless you are aware that you are making an approximation which may or may not be reasonable). When we deal with very tiny things, we need to use Quantum Mechanics in order for these new effects to be treated properly.